# Android SQLite ignore to add if world exist in ArrayList

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm using Android SQLite for add some ArrayList. I want to do this:
if have world which I'll choose in the list and in anywhere, I want to block to add this.

For example; if in ArrayList exist "Duck U", I want to ignore to add database it.

I tired `list.contains("Duck u");` but does not work.

**My code for add to database:**

```
public void HistoryADD(ArrayList<String> full, String owner){
    int size = full.size();
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    try{
        for (int i = 0; i < size ; i++){
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(FULL, full.get(i));
            cv.put(OWNER, owner);
            Log.d("Added ",""+ cv);
            db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
        }
        db.close();
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Could not added");
    }}
```

Any sample for it? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the following may be a solution (noting that it caters for multiple words (strings) to be ignored (skip the insert))

This utilises a method, namely `ifHaystackContainsNeedle` that will search an ArrayList (the Haystack)against another ArrayList (the Needle) (thus catering for multiple strings to ignore). This methods returns true if any of the needles are found the the haystack. So if this returns true you can just continue the for loop, thus skipping the

```
public void HistoryADD(ArrayList<String> full, String owner,ArrayList<String> ignore){
    int size = full.size();
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    try{
        for (int i = 0; i < size ; i++){
            //<<<<<<<<<< START OF ADDED TEST
            if (ifHaystackContainsNeedle,owner,ignore) {
                Log.d("Skipped ","Owner " + get(i) + " was skipped.");
                continue;
            }
            //<<<<<<<<<< END OF ADDED TEST
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(FULL, full.get(i));
            cv.put(OWNER, owner);
            Log.d("Added ",""+ cv);
            db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
        }
        db.close();
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Could not added");
    }}


//<<<<<<<<<< NEW METHOD
private boolean ifHaystackContainsNeedle(ArrayList<String> haystack, ArrayList<String> needle) {
    for (String s: haystack) {
        for (String s2: needle) {
            if (s.contains(s2)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

- **Note** this is in-principle code and has been been fully tested and may therefore contain some errors.

Comment: I modified your sample and it's works!

Thanks honey :*